# Recursive generator for change money - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

First, thanks for any help.

I have this recursive code for counting ways of change from a list of coins and a given amount.

I need to write a recursive generator code that presents the ways in every iteration. Example at the end:

This is the code:

```
def countChange(amount, coins):
    if (amount == 0):
        return 1
    elif (amount < 0 or coins == []):
        return 0
    else:
    return (countChange(amount, coins[:-1]) + countChange(amount - coins[-1], coins))
```

Now, I need to present the ways with a recursive generator. I have a part of the code that I need to write:

```
def change_gen(amount, coins):
    if amount == 0:
       yield ?????
    elif not (amount < 0 or coins == []):
       g = change_gen(amount, coins[:-1])
       ?????
```

This should be the output for example:

```
 for e in change_gen(5,[1,2,3]):
     print(e)

 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 1, 2]
 [1, 2, 2]
 [1, 1, 3]
 [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Btw this reminds me of [Problem 31](https://projecteuler.net/problem=31).

If you are using **Python 3.3+** we can write `change_gen` with [`yield from`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/):

```
def change_gen(amount, coins):
    if amount == 0:
        yield 1
    elif amount < 0 or not coins:
        yield 0
    else:
        yield from change_gen(amount, coins[:-1])
        yield from change_gen(amount - coins[-1], coins)
```

or without `yield from`

```
def change_gen(amount, coins):
    if amount == 0:
        yield 1
    elif amount < 0 or not coins:
        yield 0
    else:
        for element in change_gen(amount, coins[:-1]):
            yield element
        for element in change_gen(amount - coins[-1], coins):
            yield element
```

## Tests

```
import random


for _ in range(10):
    amount = random.randint(0, 900)
    coins = list({random.randint(1, 100)
                  for _ in range(random.randint(1, 10))})
    assert countChange(amount, coins) == sum(change_gen(amount, coins))
```

worked fine, so it seems to give similar output

## Note

You should remember that for large values of `amount` and small coins we may reach recursion limit (max depth is near `1000` on my machines).

---

## EDIT

if you want to get which coins were used we can add extra parameter for them

```
def change_gen(amount, left_coins, used_coins):
    if amount == 0:
        yield used_coins
    elif amount < 0 or not left_coins:
        yield
    else:
        yield from change_gen(amount, left_coins[:-1],
                              used_coins=used_coins[:])
        yield from change_gen(amount - left_coins[-1],
                              left_coins,
                              used_coins[:] + [left_coins[-1]])
```

possible problem here is that in situations when amount is negative or no coins left `None` object will be yielded, but it's ok, we can filter them from results using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
for e in filter(None, change_gen(5, [1, 2, 3], used_coins=[])):
    print(e)
```

gives us

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 1]
[3, 2]
```

Comment: but i need to write on the pattern that i gave.

Comment: >>> for e in change_gen(5,[1,2,3]):
 print(e)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
[2, 3]
this should be output

Comment: @AvriFridenson: `countChange` doesn't return what you've written, edit answer so everyone can understand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583060/change-money-code-using-recursive-generator

Comment: @AvriFridenson: you should edit current question instead of creating another one

Comment: im sorry it is my first time here, can you help me with this?

Comment: tnx. now, i will be glad if you can help me to solve this:)

Comment: @AvriFridenson: edited, let me know if it worked as expected or can be improved

Comment: first, thank you very much for the effort. but the task was to stick to the pattern and you change the pattern and the input of the function. i really aprriciate what you have done

Comment: @AvriFridenson: what do you mean? at first you need to make recursive generator from given function, then you need recursive generator which yields lists of coins decomposition, then you say that we should "stick to the pattern"? what "pattern"? you want to leave signature unchanged? dude, what a stupid task

Comment: look at my answer downwards

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this is the pattern.
i asked to complete it

Comment: where did you get this from? whoever teach you programming – he is not a good teacher at all – main thing is that code should do job and do it correctly, it is not "fill-the-gap" game