# change money code- using recursive generator

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, recursion, generator

first, thank for any help.
i have this recursive code for counting ways of change from a list of coins and a given amount. i need to write a recursive generator code that presents the ways in every iteration.
example at the end:

this is the code:

```
def countChange(amount, coins):
    if (amount == 0):
        return 1
    elif (amount < 0 or coins == []):
        return 0
    else:
    return (countChange(amount, coins[:-1]) + countChange(amount - coins[-1], coins))
```

now, i need to present the ways with a recursive generator. i have part of the code that i need to write:

```
def change_gen(amount, coins):
    if amount == 0:
       yield ?????
    elif not (amount < 0 or coins == []):
       g = change_gen(amount, coins[:-1])
       ?????
```

this should be the output for example:

```
 for e in change_gen(5,[1,2,3]):
     print(e)

 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 1, 2]
 [1, 2, 2]
 [1, 1, 3]
 [2, 3]
```

Comment: What isn't working? what are you having trouble with?

Comment: I do not sucsses with writing the generator function. I shared the pattern of how the code should look like.

Comment: Its still unclear which part you're struggling with, if its how to use the `yield` function, then you just need to put `yield 1` and then follow this example for your other logic.

Comment: if you put yield 1 you wiil get numbers, but i need list of the change money. i dont know how to write the code

Comment: Why do you want  a generator? Is it not OK to generate a list of lists of the change directly? That is easier than having to get the recursive generator working correctly.

Comment: it is a task from the university

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recursive generator for change money - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575298/recursive-generator-for-change-money-python)